# Load data into Amazon Redshift from S3 with quotation marks

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

How can I load data from Amazon S3 where the data in my input file is within quotation marks and fields are comma-delimited?

Sample input:

```
 “A”,”ENGLAND”,”West, City Center”,”100”,”200”
```

I used the below query:

```
 copy users from 's3://awssampledbuswest2/tickit/allusers_pipe.txt' 
     credentials 'aws_iam_role=>iam-role-arn>' 
     delimiter ',' region 'us-west-2';
```

The value `"West, City Center"` has a comma in it, so it cannot load the data properly.

How can I define the text qualifier to load this data?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `REMOVEQUOTES` parameter of the Amazon Redshift `COPY` command.

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-removequotes):

> Removes surrounding quotation marks from strings in the incoming data. All characters within the quotation marks, including delimiters, are retained. If a string has a beginning single or double quotation mark but no corresponding ending mark, the COPY command fails to load that row and returns an error.